# How to retrieve old facebook/XMPP messages as well as new with kopete?

Tags: facebook, xmpp, kopete

I have been considering using Kopete to use Facebook chat instead of logging on to Facebook with a web browser. That way, I can integrate messages with my KDE desktop better. The problem is, when I open Kopete, I am unable to see messages that I recieved in Facebook while Kopete was not opened. I can only see messages that I sent or received when Kopete was open. The same thing happens in Outlook.com (which is a website that connects to Facebook), Pidgin software, and other instant messaging tools.

So my question is, how can I receive these messages with a desktop chat application in KDE, such as Kopete? Facebook has made their API publicly available to developers, and KDE has its own Facebook integration plugin. So it would seem achievable.